# How to transform a vector to a matrix with each line equal to the vector in pytorch?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch

for exemple I have the vector `[1, 2, 3]`

I want to get a matrix like

```
[[1, 2, 3],
[1, 2, 3],
[1, 2, 3],
[1, 2, 3]]
```

How to do that efficiently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look at [`.repeat()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.repeat):

```
In [1]: torch.Tensor([1, 2, 3]).repeat(4, 1)
Out[1]: 
tensor([[1., 2., 3.],
        [1., 2., 3.],
        [1., 2., 3.],
        [1., 2., 3.]])
```